# cout partially print without endl

Tags: c++, cout, output

I'm printing a bunch of strings as following:

```
cout<<count<<"|"<<newTime.time<<"|"<<newCat<<"|"<<newCon<<endl;
```

in which count is a counter, newTime.time is a string of time, and newCat and newCon are both strings.
The output is like following:

```
06:02:11:20:08|DB Mgr|Sending query: “SELECT * FROM users”
```

Apparently, it left out the count and "|". However, if I change the code into

```
cout<<count<<"|"<<endl;
cout<<newTime.time<<"|"<<newCat<<"|"<<newCon<<endl;
```

The output just turned into

```
2|
06:02:11:20:08|DB Mgr|Sending query: “SELECT * FROM users”
```

I was first thinking if this is the problem of buffer. I changed endl to flush but the problem still exists.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `cout<<count<<"|"<<newTime.time`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *sounds* like your `time` string may have a carriage return `\r` in it. If that's the case, then outputting using your first method will *still* output the count and separator, but the `\r` will return to the start of the line and begin overwriting it.

Your second method will not overwrite the count since it's on the previous line (a `\r` will have little visible effect if you're already at the start of the line).

If you're running on a UNIX-like platform, you can pipe the output through something like `od -xcb` (a hex dump filter) to see if there is a `\r` in the output.

Alternatively, if you have a string in your code, you can see if it contains a carriage return with something like:

```
std::string s = "whatever";
size_t pos = s.find ('\r');
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    // carriage return was found.
}
```

By way of example, the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    std::string s1 = "strA";
    std::string s2 = "\rstrB";
    std::string s3 = "strC";

    std::cout << s1 << '|' << s2 << '|' << s3 << '\n';
    std::cout << "=====\n";

    std::cout << s1 << '|' << '\n';
    std::cout << s2 << '|' << s3 << '\n';

    std::cout << "=====\n";
    size_t pos = s2.find ('\r');
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        std::cout << "CR found at " << pos << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

seems to output the following:

```
strB|strC
=====
strA|
strB|strC
=====
CR found at 0
```

but in fact that first line is actually:

```
strA|(\r)strB|strC
```

where `(\r)` is the carriage return.

---

And keep in mind you rarely need `endl` - it's effectively a `\n` with a flush which is not really necessary in most cases. You can just get away with using `\n` and let the automated flushing take care of itself.

Comment: I've changed to code to `if (newTime.time[0] == '\r')
            newTime.time[0] = ' ';
        cout<<count<<"|"<<newTime.time.c_str()<<"|"<<newCat<<"|"<<newCon<<endl;` but seems to still not working.

Comment: @ljhljh235, it's not _necessarily_ at the start. It's hard to tell since `06:02:11:20:08` is a rather unusual time format, not one I've seen before. You're better off checking the entire string.

Comment: already checked the whole string but the problem is still there. My time string is strictly created in the format mm:dd:hh:mm:ss and is strictly at the beginning of a line in a file stream. I read it by `getline(fin, oneline); Timestamp newTime(oneline.substr(0, 14));`

Comment: Problem solved. The problem truly is that there's some strange characters in the input file. After I normalize the input file there's no problem now. Thanks for so much of your time!

Comment: @ljhljh235, all I can suggest is that you _check_ the actual _output_ stream from your program.